# WPF rotate automatically endless Border LinearGradientBrush clockwise without rotate the rest

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, border

I created in WPF C# a window without style. For the new window I use the *Border* element. Within I use gradient colors. My question, is it possible to rotate automatically the *LinearGradientBrush* without rotating the rest? I want rotate automatically endless in every second or similar only the border clockwise, not more.

Window with gradient Border element

[image: Window with gradient Border element]

Example demonstration what I mean

[image: Example demonstration what I mean]

Comment: should be possible, you'd rotate a lineargradientbrush using its startpoint and endpoint co-ordinates or by applying a rotatetransform to the gradient. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34538098/1132334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't bother with the rounded corners, used different colours rather than guess at yours and every second made me feel a bit dizzy, but this rotates the colour gradient:

```
<Border BorderThickness="10">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="bbrush">
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(LinearGradientBrush.StartPoint)" From="1, 0" To="0, 1" Duration="00:00:10" />
                            <PointAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.(LinearGradientBrush.StartPoint)" From="0, 1" To="1, 0" Duration="00:00:10"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Here's another way of doing this, by rotating the brush.
The things to watch out for when doing this are the rather tortuous path syntax and the fact a brush has a relativetransform rather than rendertransform.

```
    <Border BorderThickness="10">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="bbrush">
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1.0" />
                <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" x:Name="rotateBrush" />
                </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
                                                 From="0"
                                                 To="359"
                                                 Duration="00:00:10" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. Is it possible to make the rotating colour gradient seamless (0 - 360 degrees)?

Comment: You might prefer the effect of the rotatetransform I added to my post.