# C# Rotating Color Gradient Animation

Tags: c#, animation, colors, gradient

I want to animate a LinearGradientBrush so that it looks like it is rotating.

As you can see in the picture, the start point of the gradient should be at P1, and the end point at P2.

The animation should then move the start point to P2 and then from P2 back to P1 clockwise.

After this is done, the animation should end.

How do I do this?
I've tried around but can't get it to work.

[image]

Comment: Invalidate a Picturebox in a timer and draw a rotating fill in the Paint event using `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(w, w);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-w, -w);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle` with aa suitable size and an angle you increment /reverse in the Tick!the

Comment: I found this one. It works for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536534/rotating-gradient-gets-out-of-canvas-in-wpf

Comment: Well it is for WPF; you have failed to mention your traget platform..